# How to listen to deposits and confirmations of bitcoin transactions

Tags: transactions, bcoin, deposit

hello I am building a web application using nodejs, bcoin and my application provides the user with a bitcoin address in which to deposit funds, I would like to know how I can listen on my nodejs server:

- when the user deposits funds in the bitcoin address that my application provided
- The deposit has gone through 12 confirmations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bcoin full node and wallet emit JavaScript events for things like blocks and transactions, which can be listened for with a websocket client.

There is a guide to sockets and events in bcoin here: bcoin.io/guides/events.html

If you have any more questions about bcoin you can [join us on slack](https://bcoin.io/slack-signup.html) or on IRC (Libera) #bcoin

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you tell me if the websocket client notifies me only the confirmations that a transaction that I send has or also those that send me to my address?

Comment: Both sent and received TXs should be emitted by events.